# Android TextView avoid being out of view

Tags: java, android, random, textview

I create a TextView programmatically and at a random position. The problem is: If the text is long enough (e.g. "yellow") the TextView is out of range.

My code

```
private TextView createField(int textColor, String text){
    int width = Random(10, 500);
    int height = Random(10, 500);
    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
    valueTV.setText(text);
    valueTV.setTextColor(textColor);
    valueTV.setTextSize(25);
    valueTV.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    valueTV.setSingleLine(true);
    valueTV.setMaxLines(1);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llp.setMargins(width, height, 50, 50); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(llp);

    return valueTV;
}
```

How can I achieve that if the text is to long for the screen the TextView is automatically moved to the left?

Comment: why r u giving random width ? it will move left incase of large width

Comment: Maybe width is not the best word, I agree. I just wanted to set the TextView at a random position.

Answer (score 1):

If your going to add views dynamically, first you need to get the width and height of current device screen. Use the following code to get width of the screen:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Then, calculate every times to add view with remaining space available in total width in single row. My suggestion is please use each separate layout for every row.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: This idea came into my mind too. The problem is I need to calculate the max space of a LinearLayout not of the whole screen. And there is only 1 TextView at the same time shown, so no problem with rows or anything else.